# Having trouble with joint probabilities

Tags: statistics

I am stuck on the following question in my homework:

Roll two dice. Let $X$ denote the minimum of the two values that appear, and let $Y$ denote the maximum of the two values that appear.

a) Find the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$.

I've made a table for $X = 1$ to $6$ and $Y = 1$ to $6$.  $P_{XY}(1,1)$ should be $\frac{1}{36}$, $P_{XY}(1,2)$ to $P_{XY}(1,6) = \frac{1}{18}$ as $P_{XY}(1,y)$ can have a combination of $(y,1)$ and $(1,y)$, and $P_{XY}(x,y) = 0$ when $x > y$.
However, I am stuck on $X = 2-6$.  Following my reasoning, should the probability of $P_{XY}(x,y)= \frac{1}{36}$ when $x = y$, and every other $P_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{1}{18}$?

b) Find $F_{XY}(2,3)$.

According to my table listed above, $P_{XY}(2,3) = \frac{1}{18}$.  I believe $F_{XY}(x,y)$ means to use CDF, and $P_{XY}(x,y)$ means to use PDF.  How can I then find the CDF from the given information?

Thanks!

Comment: For (a), yes, your reasoning is good. You should dobule-check that your probabilities sum to 1 (they will). For (b) you will find $\sum_{i \leq 2, j \leq 3} P_{XY}(i,j)$.

Comment: @Michael ok, so that means for i≤2 and j≤3Pxy(i,j), I will add up Pxy(1,1), Pxy(1,2) all the way up to Pxy(2,3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that making a table is a good choice here. It certainly helps to visualize.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 &4&5&6 \\ \hline
1& 1,1& 1,2&1,3&1,4&1,5&1,6\\ \hline
 2&  2,1& 2,2&2,3&2,4&2,5&2,6\\ \hline
 3& 3,1 &3,2 &3,3&3,4&3,5&3,6\\ \hline
 4&  4,1& 4,2&4,3&4,4&4,5&4,6\\ \hline
 5&  5,1&5,2 &5,3&5,4&5,5&5,6\\ \hline
 6&  6,1&6,2 &6,3&6,4&6,5&6,6\\ \hline
\end{array}

Notice that cases where $x\neq y$ have probability $\frac{2}{36}$ and cases where $x=y$ have probability $\frac{1}{36}$

The joint PMF is given by

$$P_{XY}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{36} & \color{red}{x=1,y=1}\\
\frac{2}{36} & \color{red}{x=1,y=2}\\
\frac{2}{36} & \color{red}{x=1,y=3}\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=1,y=4\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=1,y=5\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=1,y=6\\
\frac{1}{36} & \color{red}{x=2,y=2}\\
\frac{2}{36} & \color{red}{x=2,y=3}\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=2,y=4\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=2,y=5\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=2,y=6\\
\frac{1}{36} & x=3,y=3\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=3,y=4\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=3,y=5\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=3,y=6\\
\frac{1}{36} & x=4,y=4\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=4,y=5\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=4,y=6\\
\frac{1}{36} & x=5,y=5\\
\frac{2}{36} & x=5,y=6\\
\frac{1}{36} & x=6,y=6\\
\end{cases}$$

$(b)$ You need to sum the probabilities associated with events where $x\leq2$ **and** $y\leq3$

A joint CDF is given by

$$F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)$$

I have colored them in red in the joint PMF.

We have

$$F_{XY}(2,3)=\frac{1}{36}+\frac{2}{36}+\frac{2}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{2}{36}=\frac{8}{36}=\frac{2}{9}$$

Comment: ah ok, so I will need to find the sum of x≤X and y≤Y when given Fxy(X,Y).  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have added that to my answer. The joint CDF is given by $F_{XY}(x,y)=P(X\leq x, Y \leq y)$